# MariaDB Procedure with ROW TYPE OF variable based on cursor

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

```
delimiter $$

CREATE PROCEDURE  `proc_test`()
BEGIN   
    DECLARE rec ROW TYPE OF c_data;
    DECLARE c_data CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM agents;
END$$
```

This procedure when called gives below error

```
Error Code: 1146. Table 'db_nvocc_local.c_data' doesn't exist
```

As per official documentation here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/declare-variable/
We should be able to declare a variable of type ROW based on cursor. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to call the procedure without error when defined as below. But not sure if it is the correct way

```
delimiter $$

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE  `proc_test`()
BEGIN 
    DECLARE c_data CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM agents;
    BEGIN
        DECLARE rec ROW TYPE OF c_data;
    END;
END$$
```